# Installing Skype on Debian x64: pkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype

Tags: debian, software-installation, dependencies, skype

I'm trying to install Skype using [this 
manual](http://wiki.debian.org/skype). I successfully download the package using the command:

```
wget -O skype-install.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb-64
```

but when I try to install the package I get some errors about dependencies:

```
root@102:~# dpkg -i skype-install.deb
(Reading database ... 27918 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace skype 4.0.0.8-1 (using skype-install.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement skype ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:
 skype depends on lib32stdc++6 (>= 4.1.1-21); however:
  Package lib32stdc++6 is not installed.
 skype depends on lib32asound2 (>> 1.0.14); however:
  Package lib32asound2 is not installed.
 skype depends on ia32-libs; however:
  Package ia32-libs is not installed.
 skype depends on libc6-i386 (>= 2.7-1); however:
  Package libc6-i386 is not installed.
 skype depends on lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1-21+ia32.libs.1.19); however:
  Package lib32gcc1 is not installed.
 skype depends on ia32-libs-gtk; however:
  Package ia32-libs-gtk is not installed.
dpkg: error processing skype (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When a package fails to **configure**, you can install the missing dependencies after the fact using `apt-get install -f`. Here is the description of `-f` from the documentation:

```
  -f, --fix-broken
     Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.
     This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages to 
     permit APT to deduce a likely solution.
```

If the package installation fails prior to the configure step do to dependencies, then those packages need to be installed manually. This is because the package declares `Pre-depends` rather than `Depends` on those packages.

Answer (score 4):

dependancies are packages your package needs to run ( for example libraries etc ). 
If you install a package trough aptitude / apt / synaptic this will check for the dependancies and download them.

If you download a .deb file and try to install it manually this might not be the case. 
As posted before you need to install the required packages before installing skype again:

f.e.:

```
aptitude install lib32stdc++6 lib32asound2 ia32-libs libc6-i386 lib32gcc1 ia32-libs-gtk
```

I'm not 100% sure the above command will work. If aptitude / apt complains that it can not find a package you can search the repositories for the correct name:

```
aptitude search ia32-libs
```

then, once that all these packages are installed you can install skype again:

```
dpkg -i skype-install.deb
```

Comment: Thanks! I installed libraries using `apt-get -f install`

Comment: that is also a possibility :-)

Comment: @Kolyunya - That's what I would consider the correct answer, and it's not mentioned in the answer you accepted.

Comment: someone is hunting for karma :/

Answer (score 3):

***Older info: Debian Jessie x64 KDE (back when it was still "testing")***

These commands are what works for me:

```
$ wget -O skype-install.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb
# dpkg --add-architecture i386
# aptitude update
# dpkg -i skype-install.deb
# aptitude install -f libc6:i386 libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386\
  libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-xml:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtgui4:i386\
  libqtwebkit4:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxss1:i386\
  libxv1:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libpulse0:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
```

Some of the packages above are dependent on each other, so this is a bit redundant, but in any case these are what `skype-install.deb` states as missing dependencies in my system.

---

***Updated info: Debian Jessie x64 (which is "stable" atm)***

A simpler and more generic set of commands, which works for KDE for certain, but should work for any environment:

```
$ wget -O skype-install.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb
# dpkg --add-architecture i386
# aptitude update
# gdebi skype-install.deb
```

More info can also be found on the [debian wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/skype).

Answer (score 1):

Open synaptic and install packages that are not installed.

Comment: I don't have any GUI, only command line.

Comment: @Kolyunya: How do you run Skype without a GUI? For me, when I type `skype` nothing happens for some seconds, then the process terminates. (And there is no man page for Skype.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install this package, Skype is statically compiled with Qt, just download the `Dynamic Static` package from skype's official site, it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the answer given by jordanm would not help so you might just run

`apt-get install libqtwebkit4:i386`
and then again

```
apt-get install -f
```

If there would be still unmet dependencies, install it same way, for example:

```
apt-get install libqt4-dbus:i386
```

After all you can run `dpkg -i skype-debian_4.*number of bield*.deb`